# How to convert a phone number to the IRI format? (Internationalized Resource Identifiers)

Tags: uri, phone-number, tel

I am discovering [W3C's IRI (aka RFC3987)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987).

How to convert a phone number (let's say I have the String `"+12-3456-789"`) to the IRI format?

Preferably in Java, but any other language is acceptable.

Or am I mistaken, and IRI can not be used for phone numbers? I guess the "tel:" protocol ([RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)) makes them acceptable, but not sure how the whole IRI works in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 3987 defines steps for [converting URIs to IRIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987#section-3.2). The only thing that may need to be changed is the percent-encoding.

Your telephone number has the following URI (according to [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)):

```
tel:+12-3456-789
```

As there are no percent-encoded characters, the IRI would be the same:

```
tel:+12-3456-789
```

Some parameters can be used in `tel` URIs, e.g., `phone-context` has to be used for local numbers, which *may* contain percent-encoded content. Following the linked conversion steps, such an `tel` URI *might* have a different IRI form.